# Bulk insert using loop

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to insert 500 records into a table (`dbo.Product`) but I am getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
>   Incorrect syntax near 'p'

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @StartLoop INT,
        @EndLoop INT,
        @ProductID INT,
        @ProductName NVARCHAR(250),
        @BestBefore DATETIME,
        @ManufactureDate datetime,
        @ProductNumber NVARCHAR(25),
        @Weight decimal, 
        @ProductStockLevelID INT 

SELECT 
    @StartLoop =1,
    @EndLoop = 500,
    @ProductID  = '',
    @ProductName = 'Yoghurt',
    @BestBefore = '',
    @ManufactureDate = '' ,
    @ProductNumber = '',
    @Weight = '', 
    @ProductStockLevelID = ''

WHILE @StartLoop <= @EndLoop
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Product p (ProductID, ProductName, BestBefore, ManufactureDate, ProductNumber, [Weight], ProductStockLevelID)
        SELECT 
            @ProductID  + CAST(@StartLoop AS INT),
            @ProductName + Cast(@startloop AS  NVARCHAR(250)),
            @BestBefore + CAST(@StartLoop AS DATETIME),
            @ManufactureDate + CAST(@startLoop AS DATETIME),
            @ProductNumber + CAST(@StartLoop AS Nvarchar(25)),
            @Weight + CAST(@StartLoop AS DECIMAL),
            @ProductStockLevelID + CAST(@StartLoop AS INT)

    SELECT @StartLoop = @StartLoop + 1 
END
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `p` in your insert command

`INSERT INTO dbo.Product p (ProductID`

to

`INSERT INTO dbo.Product (ProductID`

Reference link  [INSERT SQL MDSN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa977880(v=vs.71).aspx)

And another way to insert to your product table without `WHILE` is use `CTE` with `recursive function`

```
 ;WITH temp AS 
(
  SELECT @StartLoop AS RowIndex 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT t.RowIndex + 1
  FROM temp t
  where t.RowIndex < @EndLoop
) -- temp table result @StartLoop,@StartLoop +1 ,... -> @EndLoop 

INSERT INTO dbo.Product (ProductID, ProductName, BestBefore, ManufactureDate, ProductNumber, [Weight],ProductStockLevelID)
SELECT 
   @ProductID  + CAST(t.RowIndex AS INT),
   @ProductName + Cast(t.RowIndex AS  NVARCHAR(250)),
   @BestBefore + CAST(t.RowIndex AS DATETIME),
   @ManufactureDate + CAST(t.RowIndex AS DATETIME),
   @ProductNumber + CAST(t.RowIndex AS Nvarchar(25)),
   @Weight + CAST(t.RowIndex AS DECIMAL),
   @ProductStockLevelID + CAST(t.RowIndex AS INT)
FROM temp t
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `p` from :

`INSERT INTO dbo.Product p (ProductID`

and let it like this:

`INSERT INTO dbo.Product (ProductID`

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I removed p and it works perfectly.